# How can I make the position value only selectable when user click certain layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, mobile-development

**Background** - Here's the scenario, my app is an IOT app. In my app, there is section of Schedule for devices through which users can able to change the schedule timings of their devices. Now in certain device schedule layout, there is a button I have to create through which by clicking user can remove that schedule or edit their schedule in schedule layout. As I have create that button and after clicking it a dialog box will appear which has option of EDIT and REMOVE. Now when user click the EDIT button, a new screen or fragment screen will appear of Updated Schedule for that particular schedule from which user can modify the schedule time and devices.

**Problem** - Now the problem is I have mentioned above, and to explain it better here's the code:

```
class ScheduleFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentScheduleBinding>() {

    private var schedules = ArrayList<Schedule>()
    private val logUtils = LogUtils(LevelLogger.SCHEDULE_DEVICES)

    override fun setLayoutResource(): Int {
        return R.layout.fragment_schedule
    }

    override fun onViewReady() {
        showProgressDialog(title(R.string.please_wait))

        baseBinding.buttonCreateSchedule.setOnClickListener {
            goCreateSchedule()
        }
    }

    private fun goCreateSchedule() {
        val dashboardScreenObserver = DashboardScreenObserver()
        dashboardScreenObserver.dashboardScreens = DashboardScreens.CREATE_SCHEDULE
        dashboardScreenModuleObserver.dashboardScreenObserver.value =
            dashboardScreenObserver
    }

    private fun initializeRemoveSchedule(position: Int) {
        val schedule = schedules[position]
        val nodeIdList: MutableSet<String> = HashSet()
        val actions: ArrayList<Action> = schedule.actions
        val operation = AppConstants.KEY_OPERATION_REMOVE

        for (i in actions.indices) {
            val nodeId = actions[i].nodeId
            val deviceName = actions[i].device.deviceName
            if (!nodeIdList.contains(nodeId)) {
                nodeIdList.add(nodeId)
                val scheduleJson = JsonObject()
                scheduleJson.addProperty(AppConstants.KEY_ID, schedule.id)
                scheduleJson.addProperty(AppConstants.KEY_OPERATION, operation)
                val schArr = JsonArray()
                schArr.add(scheduleJson)
                val finalBody = JsonObject()
                finalBody.add(AppConstants.KEY_SCHEDULES, schArr)
                val body = JsonObject()
                body.add(AppConstants.KEY_SCHEDULE, finalBody)

                showProgressDialog(title(R.string.progress_update_schedule))

                val apiManager: ApiManager = ApiManager.getInstance(baseContext)
                apiManager.updateParamValue(nodeId, body, object : ApiResponseListener {
                    override fun onSuccess(data: Bundle?) {
                        logUtils.log(
                            LogUtils.line(),
                            "Schedule remove request sent successfully."
                        )

                        baseContext.runOnUiThread {
                            showProgressDialog(title(R.string.please_wait))
                            refreshStateDiscover()
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onResponseFailure(exception: Exception) {
                        errorFound(exception)
                    }

                    override fun onNetworkFailure(exception: Exception) {
                        errorFound(exception)
                    }

                    fun errorFound(exception: Exception) {
                        logUtils.log(
                            LogUtils.line(),
                            "Schedule remove failed. $exception"
                        )
                        if (exception is CloudException) {
                            alertErrorManagement(
                                exception.message!!,
                                "",
                                ErrorObject.EXCEPTION,
                                R.drawable.ic_error_background
                            )
                        } else {
                            val errMsg =
                                getString(R.string.error_schedule_remove) + "\n" + deviceName
                            alertErrorManagement(
                                errMsg,
                                "",
                                ErrorObject.EXCEPTION,
                                R.drawable.ic_error_background
                            )
                        }

                        hideProgressDialog()

                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    private fun loadTimeGadgets(
        llTimeGadgets: LinearLayoutCompat,
        tvDeviceStatus: AppCompatTextView,
        schedule: Schedule
    ) {
        llTimeGadgets.removeAllViews()

        val days = schedule.triggers[AppConstants.KEY_DAYS]!!
        if (days == 0) {
            tvDeviceStatus.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tvDeviceStatus.text = title(R.string.schedule_once)
        } else {
            val rvTimeGadgets = RecyclerView(baseContext)
            rvTimeGadgets.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(baseContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            llTimeGadgets.addView(rvTimeGadgets)

            tvDeviceStatus.visibility = View.GONE

            val scheduleDays = ArrayList<ScheduleDay>()

            val daysValue = Integer.toBinaryString(days).reversed()

            val daysNames = baseContext.resources.getStringArray(R.array.day)
            for (index in daysValue.indices) {
                if (daysValue[index].toString() == "1") {
                    val scheduleDay = ScheduleDay()
                    scheduleDay.dayName = daysNames[index]
                    scheduleDays.add(scheduleDay)
                }
            }

            val adapter = object : GenericTypeAdapter<ScheduleDay, ScheduleDeviceObserver>(object :
                ScheduleDeviceObserver {
                override fun load(scheduleDay: ScheduleDay) {
                    logUtils.log(
                        levelLogger,
                        LogUtils.line(), "schedules :: ${
                            GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(scheduleDay)
                        }"
                    )

                }

                override fun menu(it: View, schedule: Schedule) {
                    onScheduleMenuOption(it, schedule)
                }

            }) {
                override fun loadHolder(
                    parent: ViewGroup,
                    viewType: Int
                ): GenericViewHolder<ScheduleDay, ScheduleDeviceObserver> {
                    val binding = LayoutDaysBadgeBinding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                        parent,
                        false
                    )

                    return object :
                        GenericViewHolder<ScheduleDay, ScheduleDeviceObserver>(binding.root) {

                        override fun loadItems(
                            position: Int,
                            model: ScheduleDay,
                            models: ArrayList<ScheduleDay>,
                            listener: ScheduleDeviceObserver
                        ) {
                            binding.tvBadge.text = model.dayName
                            binding.tvBadge.setStrokeWidth(2f)
                            binding.tvBadge.strokeColor(R.color.white)
                            binding.tvBadge.solidColor(R.color.orange1)


                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            adapter.addRecord(scheduleDays)
            rvTimeGadgets.adapter = adapter
            rvTimeGadgets.post {
                val measureHeight = -(rvTimeGadgets.measuredHeight) / 3
                rvTimeGadgets.addItemDecoration(OverlapItemDecorator(measureHeight))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
        }

        refreshStateDiscover()
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    fun onEvent(event: UpdateEvent) {
        logUtils.log(
            LogUtils.line(),
            "Update Event Received : " + event.eventType
        )
        applicationModuleObserver.isManagerInitialize.value = ""
        hideProgressDialog()
        when (event.eventType) {
            AppConstants.UpdateEventType.EVENT_DEVICE_ADDED,
            AppConstants.UpdateEventType.EVENT_DEVICE_REMOVED -> {

            }

            AppConstants.UpdateEventType.EVENT_STATE_CHANGE_UPDATE -> {
                loadSchedules()
            }
            AppConstants.UpdateEventType.EVENT_LOCAL_DEVICE_UPDATE,
            AppConstants.UpdateEventType.EVENT_DEVICE_STATUS_UPDATE -> {
                loadSchedules()
            }
            else -> {

            }
        }
    }

    private fun loadSchedules() {

        schedules.clear()

        for ((key, schedule) in meshApplication.scheduleMap) {
            if (schedule != null) {
                schedules.add(schedule)
            }
        }

        if (schedules.size == 0) {
            var isScheduleDevicesAvailable = false
            for ((key, node) in meshApplication.localEspNode.entries) {
                val services: ArrayList<Service> = node.services
                if (node != null) {
                    for (i in services.indices) {
                        val s: Service = services[i]
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.type) && s.type
                                .equals(AppConstants.SERVICE_TYPE_SCHEDULE)
                        ) {
                            isScheduleDevicesAvailable = true
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        val adapter = object :
            GenericTypeAdapter<Schedule, ScheduleDeviceObserver>(object : ScheduleDeviceObserver {
                override fun load(scheduleDay: ScheduleDay) {

                }

                override fun menu(it: View, schedule: Schedule) {
                    onScheduleMenuOption(it, schedule)
                }

            }) {
            override fun loadHolder(
                parent: ViewGroup,
                viewType: Int
            ): GenericViewHolder<Schedule, ScheduleDeviceObserver> {
                val binding = LayoutScheduleBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                )

                return object : GenericViewHolder<Schedule, ScheduleDeviceObserver>(binding.root) {

                    override fun loadItems(
                        position: Int,
                        schedule: Schedule,
                        models: ArrayList<Schedule>,
                        listener: ScheduleDeviceObserver
                    ) {
                        binding.tvGadgetsGroupName.text = schedule.name
                        binding.ivOnlineDeviceGadgets.isSelected = schedule.isEnabled

                        val days = schedule.triggers[AppConstants.KEY_DAYS]!!
                        val time = time(schedule)
                        logUtils.log(
                            LogUtils.line(),
                            "***********",
                            time,
                            "***********",
                            GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(schedule),
                            "***********",
                            getDaysText(days)
                        )

                        // Display action devices
                        val deviceNames = StringBuilder()
                        val actions: ArrayList<Action> = schedule.actions

                        if (actions.size > 0) {
                            for (i in actions.indices) {
                                val deviceName: String = actions[i].device.userVisibleName
                                if (deviceNames.isNotEmpty()) {
                                    deviceNames.append(", ")
                                }
                                deviceNames.append(deviceName)
                            }
                        }
                        binding.tvOnTimeGadgets.text = deviceNames
                        binding.tvOffTimeGadgets.text = time

                        loadTimeGadgets(binding.llTimeGadgets, binding.tvDeviceStatus, schedule)

                        binding.clMenuDevice.setOnClickListener {
                            listener.menu(it, models[adapterPosition])
                        }

                    }

                    private fun time(schedule: Schedule): String {
                        // Display days and time of schedule
                        val scheduleTimeText = StringBuilder()

                        val triggers = schedule.triggers
                        val allMinutes = triggers[AppConstants.KEY_MINUTES]!!
                        var hour = allMinutes / 60
                        val minutes = allMinutes % 60

                        if (hour < 12) {
                            if (hour == 0) {
                                hour = 12
                            }
                            if (hour < 10) {
                                scheduleTimeText.append("0$hour:")
                            } else {
                                scheduleTimeText.append("$hour:")
                            }
                            if (minutes < 10) {
                                scheduleTimeText.append("0$minutes AM")
                            } else {
                                scheduleTimeText.append("$minutes AM")
                            }
                        } else if (hour == 12) {
                            scheduleTimeText.append("$hour:")
                            if (minutes < 10) {
                                scheduleTimeText.append("0$minutes PM")
                            } else {
                                scheduleTimeText.append("$minutes PM")
                            }
                        } else {
                            hour -= 12
                            if (hour < 10) {
                                scheduleTimeText.append("0$hour:")
                            } else {
                                scheduleTimeText.append("$hour:")
                            }
                            if (minutes < 10) {
                                scheduleTimeText.append("0$minutes PM")
                            } else {
                                scheduleTimeText.append("$minutes PM")
                            }
                        }
                        return scheduleTimeText.toString()
                    }

                    private fun getDaysText(days: Int): String {
                        val daysText = StringBuilder()
                        if (days == 0) {
                            daysText.append(title(R.string.schedule_once))
                        } else {
                            val daysStr = StringBuilder("00000000")
                            val daysValue = Integer.toBinaryString(days)
                            val daysCharValue = daysValue.toCharArray()
                            var j = 7
                            for (i in daysCharValue.size - 1 downTo 0) {
                                daysStr.setCharAt(j, daysCharValue[i])
                                j--
                            }
                            val daysStrValue = daysStr.toString()
                            if (daysStrValue == "01111111" || daysStrValue == "11111111") {
                                daysText.append(title(R.string.schedule_daily))
                            } else if (daysStrValue == "01100000" || daysStrValue == "11100000") {
                                daysText.append(title(R.string.schedule_weekends))
                            } else if (daysStrValue == "00011111" || daysStrValue == "10011111") {
                                daysText.append(title(R.string.schedule_weekdays))
                            } else {
                                val daysNames = baseContext.resources.getStringArray(R.array.days)
                                val chars = daysStrValue.toCharArray()
                                for (i in chars.size - 1 downTo 1) {
                                    if (chars[i] == '1') {
                                        val day = daysNames[i - 1]
                                        if (daysText.isEmpty()) {
                                            daysText.append(title(R.string.schedule_on_day))
                                            daysText.append(" ")
                                            daysText.append(day)
                                        } else {
                                            daysText.append(", $day")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return daysText.toString()
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        adapter.addRecord(schedules)

        baseBinding.flScheduleDevice.removeAllViews()

        if (schedules.size == 0) {
            baseBinding.buttonCreateSchedule.visibility = View.GONE

            val layoutEmpty = LayoutEmptyBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(baseContext),
                baseBinding.flScheduleDevice,
                false
            )
            layoutEmpty.btnAdd.text = "Create Schedule"
            layoutEmpty.btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
                goCreateSchedule()
            }

            baseBinding.flScheduleDevice.addView(layoutEmpty.root)

        } else {
            baseBinding.buttonCreateSchedule.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            val rvScheduleDevice = RecyclerView(baseContext)
            rvScheduleDevice.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(baseContext)
            rvScheduleDevice.adapter = adapter
            baseBinding.flScheduleDevice.addView(rvScheduleDevice)

            rvScheduleDevice.addItemDecoration(
                dividerItemDecoration(
                    R.color.transparent,
                    RecyclerView.VERTICAL,
                    1,
                    20
                )
            )

        }

    }

    private fun onScheduleMenuOption(it: View, schedule: Schedule) {
        val scheduleOperationFragment = ScheduleOperationFragment(object :
            ScheduleOperationObserver {
                override fun operate(
                    view: View,
                    scheduleOperationOperate: ScheduleOperationOperate,
                    dialogFragment: DialogFragment
                ) {
                    if (scheduleOperationOperate == ScheduleOperationOperate.EDIT) {

                        val schedule = schedules[position]

                        val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
                        val bundle = Bundle()
                        bundle.putString(
                            AppConstants.KEY_SCHEDULE,
                            Gson().toJson(schedule)
                        )

                        Navigation.findNavController(
                            baseContext,
                            R.id.childDashboardNavHostFragment
                        ).navigate(
                            R.id.updateScheduleFragment,
                            bundle,
                            navOptions.build()
                        )
                    }

                    if (scheduleOperationOperate == ScheduleOperationOperate.REMOVE) {
                        AlertOperationFragment.showAlertDialog(baseContext,
                            getString(R.string.dialog_title_delete_user),
                            getString(R.string.dialog_msg_confirmation),
                            buttonPositive,
                            buttonNegative,
                            true,
                            object : AlertOperationFragment.AlertObserver {
                                override fun success(dialog: Dialog) {
                                    initializeRemoveSchedule(position)
                                    dialog.dismiss()
                                }

                                override fun close(dialog: Dialog) {
                                    dialog.dismiss()
                                }

                            })
                    }

                }
            }
        )

        scheduleOperationFragment.apply {
            setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.OperateDialog)
        }
        scheduleOperationFragment.show(childFragmentManager, scheduleOperationFragment.tag)

    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
    }

    interface ScheduleOperationObserver {
        fun operate(
            view: View,
            scheduleOperationOperate: ScheduleOperationOperate,
            dialogFragment: DialogFragment
        )
    }

    interface ScheduleDeviceObserver {
        fun load(scheduleDay: ScheduleDay)

        fun menu (it: View, schedule: Schedule)
    }
}
```

In this code there is a variable position which is used for telling the index value or position of schedule in the array of schedule. And the position variable is using in two function, initializeRemoveSchedule and onScheduleMenuOption. Now what I want is that when user click on any schedule layout, it will open particularly for that updated schedule layout not another one. Cause if i create a global variable position and fixed its value equal to 0 then it will show updated schedule layout of only 1st schedule layout, means if their are 10 schedule in array of schedule and user select 5th schedule and try to edit it, it will show the updated layout of 1st Device.

I tried to see other two files like

ScheduleOperation.kt

```
data class ScheduleOperation(
    var title: String,
    var scheduleOperationOperate: ScheduleOperationOperate = ScheduleOperationOperate.REMOVE
)

enum class ScheduleOperationOperate {
    REMOVE,
    EDIT
}
```

ScheduleOperationFragment.kt

```
class ScheduleOperationFragment(private var scheduleOperationObserver: ScheduleFragment.ScheduleOperationObserver) : BaseDialogFragment<FragmentScheduleOperationBinding>() {


    private lateinit var mScheduleOperation: ArrayList<ScheduleOperation>

    override fun setLayoutResource(): Int {
        return R.layout.fragment_schedule_operation
    }

    override fun onViewReady() {
        mScheduleOperation = ArrayList()
        mScheduleOperation.add(ScheduleOperation("Edit", ScheduleOperationOperate.EDIT))
        mScheduleOperation.add(ScheduleOperation("Remove", ScheduleOperationOperate.REMOVE))

        val scheduleOperationAdapter = object : GenericTypeAdapter<ScheduleOperation, ScheduleOperationDialogObserver>(
            object : ScheduleOperationDialogObserver {
                override fun operate(
                    view: View,
                    scheduleOperationOperate: ScheduleOperationOperate,
                    dialogFragment: DialogFragment
                ) {
                    scheduleOperationObserver.operate(view, scheduleOperationOperate, dialogFragment)
                }

            }) {
            override fun loadHolder(
                parent: ViewGroup,
                viewType: Int
            ): GenericViewHolder<ScheduleOperation, ScheduleOperationDialogObserver> {
                val layoutScheduleOperation = LayoutScheduleOperationBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                )

                return object : GenericViewHolder<ScheduleOperation, ScheduleOperationDialogObserver>(layoutScheduleOperation.root) {
                    override fun loadItems(
                        position: Int,
                        model: ScheduleOperation,
                        models: ArrayList<ScheduleOperation>,
                        listener: ScheduleOperationDialogObserver
                    ) {
                        layoutScheduleOperation.title.text = mScheduleOperation[adapterPosition].title

                        itemView.setOnClickListener {
                            listener.operate(it, mScheduleOperation[adapterPosition].scheduleOperationOperate, this@ScheduleOperationFragment)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        scheduleOperationAdapter.addRecord(mScheduleOperation)
        baseDialogBinding.rvScheduleOperation.adapter = scheduleOperationAdapter

        val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(baseContext, R.drawable.ic_vertical_divider)

        val dividerItemDecoration =
            DividerItemDecorator(drawable!!)
        baseDialogBinding.rvScheduleOperation.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)

    }

    interface ScheduleOperationDialogObserver {
        fun operate(view: View, scheduleOperationOperate: ScheduleOperationOperate, dialogFragment: DialogFragment)
    }
```

But I didn't found any error in here. I am new in Android so I don't get much idea where I can see else.